# Most fitting Http Request

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I Develop an Email application. Database contains folders which contains emails.

Say I have an email in Inbox, and I want to move that email to Trash, meaning only change the Email's property of   FolderId.

Which Http request is the most fitting for this type of operation?

I have an Http Post for creating a new email, but It seems like a waste to take POST for this simple operation.

Thanks

Comment: It's semantically a PUT operation. Thats only semantics though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which Http request is the most fitting for this type of operation?

The `PUT` HTTP verb seems most appropriate for this use case. It is most commonly used when you want to update some existing resource. For example you might have something along the lines of:

```
PUT /email/{id_of_message} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "FolderId": "the trash folder id"
}
```

Alternatively you could just use the `DELETE` verb if you think it would better fit the semantics of *moving an email resource to the trash*:

```
DELETE /email/{id_of_message} HTTP/1.1
```

Obviously behind the scenes your method implementation would do the same action in both cases: update the `FolderId` property of the email resource specified by the identifier provided by the client in the path segment of the request.